# What can i do to have aninmation Node version 2.0 or 2.1 python 3.7 build work on my linux? I am using Fedora 32

Tags: python, animation-nodes

[image: Animation Node build does not work.]

The error message made it clear, the build i was installing isn't working at the moment.

Comment: Are you using  a blender version from blender.org? Fedora is known for having versions that don't include all of the necessary libraries for blender.

Comment: Installed blender using snap.

Comment: I have that also version 2.9, and have tried installing the add-on manually but the i receive the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of the add-on worked, after upgrading to Blender version 2.9, downloaded the daily build from the GraphicAll Community.

I recommend downloading  the version compactible to your OS from the GraphicAll community installation of the add-on downloaded from the official Animation Nodes website or the GitHub page fails.

This should work, especially if you're on linux...this could work for Windows as well.

GraphicAll Community
"https://blender.community/c/graphicall"